# c++ Accessing specific value in Single Linked List

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

My list contains a name and a campus id(CWID). How can i compare the cwid that is in my list to the integer i am passing in? I wrote the psuedo code of the comparison below of what i am trying to do.

```
void check_cwid(studentList& list, int cwid) {

studentNode *p = list.head_;

while(p != nullptr){

 //Something like this 
   if *p.cwid() == cwid
  //do something

  p = p->next_;

}
```

I am trying to accomplish what is in the code above. I just dont know how to compare specific items in my list. Here is my entire practice project below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student {

public:

    student(const string& sname = "", int cwid = 0) : sname_(sname), cwid_(cwid) {}

    string sname() const {return sname_;}
    int cwid() const {return cwid_;}

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, student st){
        return os << endl << st.sname_ << endl << st.cwid_ << endl;
    }



private:

    string sname_;
    int cwid_;

};


struct studentNode {

    studentNode(const string& sname, int cwid, studentNode* next=nullptr) :st_(sname, cwid), next_(next) {}

    studentNode(student& st, studentNode* next=nullptr) : st_(st), next_(next) {}

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, studentNode node) {
        return os << node.st_;
    }


    studentNode* next_;
    student st_;

};

struct studentList {

    studentList() : head_(nullptr), size_(0) {}

    studentNode* head_;
    size_t size_;

};


///******************** what im trying to do
void check_cwid(studentList& list, int cwid) {

    studentNode *p = list.head_;

    while(p != nullptr){




    }
}
```

Comment: That is a giant mountain of code and it's cluttered with vast amounts of white space. Can you clean it up and delete anything not strictly related to the problem at hand?

Comment: ok how about now

Comment: Still a lot of dead space there, plus mystery code that distracts from the core of the problem, whatever that is. Read up on [how to make a good minimal, self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you less critique my code and help me solve it. Obviously my point is getting out there. I am new here just relax.

Comment: It's because you're new here I'm taking time to explain: Presentation is important. The way these things scroll is awful and the more code you have, the harder it is to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int check_cwid(studentList& list, int cwid) {

studentNode *p = list.head_;
int list_size = list.size_;
while(list_size--){

 //Something like this 
   if (p -> st_.cwid() == cwid)
  //do something
   break;
   else
       p = p -> next_;

}
```

Comment: Fixed. Could't you did it by yourself? Just wrote st instead of st_.

Comment: Thank you i tried that but was getting an error for some . reason but now its working.

Comment: Thank you! for your time and help.